# JavaScript Sort Array through value and display in HTML table

Tags: javascript

So, I have this list and I need to sort them after a certain brand of car. For example, Audi. And display them in an HTML table, one column with names and the other one with vehicles owned, the first ones being the Audi vehicle owners and then the others. How can I do that?

```
const people = [
  { name: "Ana", cars: "Audi" },
  { name: "Victoria", cars: ["Audi", "BMW"] },
  { name: "Grace", cars: ["Volkwagen", "Audi"] },
  { name: "Dan", cars: ["Opel", "Volkswagen"] },
  { name: "Josh", cars: ["Opel"] },
  { name: "John", cars: ["BMW", "Jaguar"] },
  { name: "Damon", cars: ["Renault", "Mercedes", "Audi"] },
];
```

Thank you!

Comment: have you taken a look at sort? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 0):

Using `reduce()` you could group the car's owners.

```js
const people = [
  { name: "Ana", cars: ["Audi"] },
  { name: "Victoria", cars: ["Audi", "BMW"] },
  { name: "Grace", cars: ["Volkswagen", "Audi"] },
  { name: "Dan", cars: ["Opel", "Volkswagen"] },
  { name: "Josh", cars: ["Opel"] },
  { name: "John", cars: ["BMW", "Jaguar"] },
  { name: "Damon", cars: ["Renault", "Mercedes", "Audi"] }
];

var brands = people.reduce((acc, o) => {
  o.cars.forEach(c => {
    if (!(c in acc)) acc[c] = [];
    acc[c].push(o.name);
  });
  return acc;
}, {});

var cont = document.getElementById("brands");

for (let b in brands) {
  var brand = document.createElement("p");
  brand.innerHTML = "<b>" + b + "</b>: " + brands[b].join(" ");
  cont.appendChild(brand);
}


//console.log(brands);
```

```html
<p>Brands and owners</p>
<div id="brands">

</div>
```

Comment: sorry, I still can't manage to write a good solution to sort using a certain brand. For example, all the elements in the list with Volkswagen to be shown first and then the others.